# Live Charts in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I'm trying to import a large set of data from excel into wpf and then use live charts to display the data in a moving line graph as it reads the through excel document. Is there a loop code I can use for this? and is live charts able to do this?

Comment: Hello, I had an experience with Live Charts in WPF, Could you add details to your question? Also you can add [LiveCharts] tag to your question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what you said live charts is https://lvcharts.net. Why not try it's Document? https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/wpf/start

Comment: Unfortunately the documents are lacking when it comes to trying to build more advanced dynamic charts.